# How to run async mocha tests in their order?

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js

Take the below code:

```
describe('foobar', function () {
   it('foo', async () => {
      // ############ API Call ############
      let foo = await chaiHttpUtil.postRequest(yadda, yadda yadda);
      // ############ Verify results ############
      expect(foo).to.have.status(200);
   ));
   it('bar', async () => {
      // ############ API Call ############
      let bar = await chaiHttpUtil.postRequest(yadda, yadda yadda);
      // ############ Verify results ############
      expect(bar).to.have.status(200);
   ));
));
```

When the above is run, I see that the first "it" (i.e. foo) is kicked off then, instead of waiting for it to finish, it then kicks off the second "it" (i.e. bar).

How can I get bar to wait until foo is completed? Can I? I understand the nature of `async` is so that it is just waiting to finish, but can I put something in the bar to get it to wait for the first to complete?

---

Update:

I made each test independent from state and each other.   Works great now.   Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Your expectiation that `it` run after one another is incorrect. (You only await the post request, not the `it` itself.) Also, each it should be independent of one another. You either should have your code in one `it` statement or create them dynamically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137899/running-mocha-tests-synchronously

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by, @k0pernikus, "each it should be independent of one another".

Some possible solutions:

1. You could combine the tests into one `it` function since they are dependent on one another.
2. State changes should not be propagated to other tests and the state should be restored for each test. Using `beforeEach`/`afterEach` hooks can help you achieve this. See: https://mochajs.org/#using-async-await
3. You could utilize this delayed root-setup
   (https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite), but I don't suspect this
   is what you're looking for.

Another thing to note is that:

> Passing arrow functions (aka “lambdas”) to Mocha is discouraged.

You should be using

```
it('bar', async function () { //... });
```

instead of

```
it('bar', async () => { //... });
```

See: https://mochajs.org/#arrow-functions